# how do I use react router with parameters, when not all my parameters always required?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a "simple" indexing page of youtube videos with the MERN stack, but I'm stuck at this part.

This is my collection model for mongodb:

```
const replaySchema = new Schema({

    game: {type: String, requiered:true},
    link: {type: String, requiered:true,unique: true},
    player1: {type: String, required: true},
    player2: {type: String, required: true},
    character1: {type: String, required: true},
    character2: {type: String, required: true},
    winner: {type: String, required: true}


},{
    timestamps:true,

});

const Replay = mongoose.model('Replay', replaySchema);
```

So the user fills a form and the object gets sent to the database.

This is when my problem comes in. Then, I'd like the user to be able to fill a similar form to query the database for the replays that follow his filters. For example, the user might want to see all the replays that are saved from a certain player, or from a certain player in a certain game, or from a certain character used by a certain player vs another player.

As you can see, there are times where the param "game" of the url would not be necessary and similarly with all the other variables.

I was going to approach it this way. The user fills the filter form, the values are taken from it and create the query url on submit of the form, which redirects to a component with a table with the desired data (replays). I've been trying to use react-router-dom for this in this kind o way:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">


        <br/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ReplaysList} />
        <Route path="/create" exact component={CreateReplay} />
        <Route path="/search" exact component={SearchReplay} />
        <Route path="/search/:game/:p1/:ch1/:p2/:ch2/:w" exact component={SearchReplay} />


      </div>

    </Router>
    // Hay que introducir un route que tenga los parametros posibles introducidos por un formulario
  );
}
```

But then I don't know what to really do on the search.js route file. Is it even able to receive just some parameters of the url and work with that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it may be cleaner to use URL query parameters. So, given a `path="/search"`

```
<Route path="/search" exact component={SearchReplay} />
```

You can access the query parameters from the [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) route prop.

```
location.search
```

You can construct a URL as

```
/search?game=someGame&p1=player1&ch1=char1&p2=player2&ch2=char2&w=player2
```

The `location.search` returns the string representing the query parameters

```
"?game=someGame&p1=player1&ch1=char1&p2=player2&ch2=char2&w=player2"
```

But you can use any query string processor to extract an object representing the query parameters

```
import qs from 'query-string';

...
qs.parse(location.search)
```

yields

```
{
  game: 'someGame',
  p1: 'player1',
  ch1: 'char1',
  p2: 'player2',
  ch2: 'char2',
  w: 'player2',
}
```

Query Parameter Processing DEMO

[image: Edit url query parameter processing]

Comment: that url format you are suggesting is exactly how I've seen similar webpages do it (example http://melty.games/ basically has the same functionality I want), but how would I handle the possibility of that url not having all paramaters? wouldn't I have to do a <Route path=diferenturl exact component={SearchReplay} /> for all possibilities? That is the part I can't really get my head around.

Comment: @VictorRosado You can express as many or as few as you want, in any order, and they will be processed. I just realized I answered for using the route's match params and ***not*** the query parameters. Will update answer and provide demo.

Comment: @VictorRosado Update answer. As stated, you can pass as many or as few as you want, but just remember you'll need to check their existence first before attempting to use any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use query params. but if you don't want to use that, you can have more than one route like below:

```js
<Route path="/search/:game/:p1/:ch1/" exact component={SearchReplay} />
<Route path="/search/:game/:p1/:ch1/:p2/:ch2/" exact component={SearchReplay} />
<Route path="/search/:game/:p1/:ch1/:p2/:ch2/:w" exact component={SearchReplay} />
```